# Javascript API only running once in a foreach loop - Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5

My objective is to collect data (`hash`) for an API from my database, once collected, my js file uses that data for the API call. The API result is then shown on the blade.php page. At this moment in time, my API is only working for one result.

File: `review.blade.php`

```
@foreach($reviews as $review)
   <div class="container card-header">
      <h3>{{ $review->company }}</h3>
      <h5><a href="/reviews/{{ $review->id }}">{{ $review->title }}</a></h5>           
      <h5 id="source">{{ $review->hash }}</h5>                     
   </div>
   <div class="container card-body">
      <p id="content"></p>
   </div>
@endforeach
```

All of the review details from the DB are shown, without any problems.

JS Code:

```
function display () {

      // Assigning variables
      var hash = document.getElementById('source').innerHTML;

      // IPFS API
      ipfs.cat(hash, {buffer: true}, function (err, res) {
        if (err || !res) {
          return console.error('ipfs cat error', err, res)
        }

        document.getElementById('content').innerText = res.toString()
      })
    }  // function closes

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', display())
```

The JS only runs once for a single hash. I'm not sure what to do. Any advice is welcome.

Comment: convert #source to .source and use querySelectorAll. Make sure there are no id's

Comment: `id="source"` in a loop will create multiple elements with the same ID, which is invalid. Change to class logic or append something to the id to make it unique.

Comment: `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', display())` assigns `undefined` as the handler. `display` is the function, `display()` is the return of the function.